# Render multiple forms, including rendering form elements, in a template

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm sending an array of forms to a template, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to get the opening and closing form tags to print if I want to render individual form elements.

Here's an example to give you an idea of the structure being sent to the theme function:

```
function mymodule_page_callback() {
  ...
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($widgets as $widget) {
    $forms[] = drupal_get_form('my_renderable_form_' . $i, $widget);
    $i++;
  }
  return theme('my_theme_function', array('forms' => $forms));
}
```

In my template, I am building a table with 1 form per row. This is the only way I can make it work:

```
$header = array('field 1', 'field 2', '');
foreach ($variables['forms'] as $form) {
  $row = array(
    drupal_render($form['field1']),
    drupal_render($form['field2']),
    // Manually set the closing form tag
    drupal_render($form['submit']) . drupal_render_children($form) . '</form>'
  );
  // Now drupal_render($form) to get the opening/closing form tags
  // and stuff it at the beginning of the 1st column.
  // This has to be done last so the rest of the form doesn't render with it.
  $row[0] = str_replace('</form>', '', drupal_render($form)) . $row[0];
  $rows[] = $row;
}
print theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows);
```

Is there a proper way to render the opening and closing of each form here?

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using `drupal_render` on individual form elements, use [`render`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/render/7) on the whole form:

```
$header = array('field 1', 'field 2', '');
foreach ($variables['forms'] as $form) {
  $rows[] = array(array('data' => render($form), 'colspan' => 3));
}
print theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows);
```

You should probably look into using the [`tableselect`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#tableselect) Form API element.

Edit: Updated the $rows[] assignment as specified in [`theme_table`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) documentation.

Comment: You are suggesting I assign rendered form to a table row, which is required to be an array... and if that worked, the problem involves rendering individual form elements (part of the title). I don't think tableselect would address the 1 form per row objective, and 1 form per table is easy to accomplish anyway. I probably should have taken the table out of the example since it is more about theming an array of forms in a single template, including rendering individual elements of those forms. I'd be happy to be wrong if there is something I am not understanding.

Comment: You're right. Table rows have to be an array. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Tableselect would not address your goal of 1 form per row. But, I'm suggesting you reconsider your design in a way to use tableselect instead of having a submit button on each row. I don't know your exact use case, but I very much suspect that this is doable and even preferable in your scenario.

Comment: You're still providing bad code, and no real work around, although I'm not looking for a workaround. I was surprised there was no way to handle rendering multiple forms in a template, when wanting control over rendering individual form elements. My question was purely to confirm if there was a way to accomplish that.